# Isometry from closed operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I have a following problem
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space.
We have a closed densely defined operator $A \colon D \subset H \rightarrow H$,

we know that $\|Ax\| = \|x\|$ for all $x \in D$, can we extend it to the isometry on $H$?

My approach:

Take $x \in H$, we can find a sequence $(x_n)$ in $D$ such that $\|x - x_n \| \rightarrow 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Since the graph of $A$ is closed in $H \times H$, then take a sequence $(x_n, Ax_n)$, 
we have that $\|(x_n, Ax_n)\| = \|x_n \| + \|Ax_n\| = 2 \|x_n \| \to 2\|x\|$, thus
$\|Ax_n \| \to \|x\|$. If we show that $Ax_n$ converges to $x$ weakly, then we will get the strong convergence of $Ax_n \to x$ which will end the proof. 
Let $y \in H$, we have $\left<y, Ax_n \right> = \left<y,Ax_n\right> = \left<A^*y, x_n \right>$ and it converges to $\left<A^*y, x\right>= \left<y, Ax\right>$, so we obtain the weak convergence. Thus, $A$ is really an isometry and it is defined on the whole $H$.

Is my proof correct? I'm not sure whether my weak convergence proof is ok. THank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is ok, but complicated. The use of the statement that "weak convergence $z_n\to_w z$ and $||z_n||\to||z||$ imply $z_n\to z$" is unnecessary.

It is easier to prove that every closed densely defined bounded operator $A$ is defined on the whole $H.$ It solves your problem.

**Proof.** Take $x_n\to x,\ x_n\in D(A),\ x\in H.$ Then $$||Ax_n-Ax_m||\leq ||A||\cdot||x_n-x_m||\to 0,\ n,m\to\infty,$$ hence $Ax_n$ converges. You have then $x\in D(A)$ by closedness of $A.$